# Python задача помогите

Tags: python

Мне надо в этом коде Python

```
N = int(input('Кол-во '))
a = 0 
for i in range(N):
    a = int(input('число '))
print()
```

сделать так чтобы мы вводили `a` и каждое `a` добавляли в переменную например `b` и потом вывели `b` и там были все эти числа в строке.

Comment: я перечитал раз 10 и понял только половину

Comment: можно пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: например ввели N 3 
вводим 3 числа получается например 3 4 2 и у нас выводится 342

Comment: @Danis первый ваш вариант с join был верным

Comment: В итоге, это вопрос про то, как вывести склеенный список. Почему нельзя писать вопросы понятнее?

Comment: @vp_arth, похоже еще до знаков пунктуации не дошли, а программирование начали учить )

Answer (score 3):

```
b="".join(input()for _ in range(int(input())))
```

это можно записать так:

```
N = int(input('Кол-во '))
h = ""
for i in range(N):
    h += input('число ')

print(h)
```

Comment: если выводить b проверьте что получается....

Comment: @user417803 уберите пробел между кавычками, будет просто строка

Comment: непонятно что получается

Comment: `b = "".join([input('число ')for _ in range(int(input('Кол-во ')))])`

Comment: @user417803 тут у вас в переменной b все и хранится, но вы же даже не знаете что такое переменная... Вывод print(b)

Comment: я знаю что такое переменная, ток смотрите, хороший вариант 
N = int(input('Кол-во '))
a = 0
b = []
for i in range(N):
    a = int(input('число '))
    b.append(a)
h = *b, sep = ""
print(h) 
только вот оно не работает а мне примерно так надо тоесть чтобы h итог был

Comment: Думаю лучший вариант. Единственное чешутся руки принудительно привести input к str. )

Comment: Зачем? input и так str..

Comment: В принципе то да. Чаще приходится приводить к int видимо уже привычка. Поэтому и со смайликом  ))

Answer (score 3):

вам надо это что ли?

```
N = int(input('Кол-во '))

b = 0 
for i in range(N):
    a = int(input('число '))
    b += a

print(b)
```

ну или так:

```
b = sum([int(input('число ')) for _ in range(int(input())])
print(b)
```

> о, только так чтобы числа не сплюсовывались а просто в строку рядом записывались –

все, теперь понял

```
N = int(input('Кол-во '))

arr = [] 
for i in range(N):
    a = int(input('число '))
    arr.append(a)

print(*arr, sep=' ')
```

ну или так:

```
arr = [int(input('число ')) for _ in range(int(input())]
print(*arr, sep=' ')
```

Comment: о, только так чтобы числа не сплюсовывались а просто в строку рядом записывались

Comment: кажется понял - добавил код

Comment: все равно выводится [2, 3, 4]

Comment: надо без квадратных скобок как то и без запятых, чтобы было 234

Comment: звёздочки не хватает) `print(*arr, sep='')`

Comment: точно, что-то я заработался - @user417803, подправил код, если вам надо и без пробелов то тогда `sep=''` сделайте

Comment: о всё, пасиба, ток мне надо чтобы вывод был какой то переменной

Comment: как это сделать??

Comment: вот так `print(*arr, sep='')`

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```py
N = int(input('Кол-во '))
a = 0
b = []
for i in range(N):
    a = int(input('число '))
    b.append(a)
# print(*b, sep = "")
c = int(''.join((str(i) for i in b)))
print(c)
```

На выходе список всех введенных а.

Comment: можно так чтобы не в квадратных скобках и это без запятых а рядом?

Comment: Дополнил код для печати списка

Comment: можно как то слитно чтобы при вводе 2 3 4 было 234

Comment: в конце можно написать `print(*b, sep = "")`

Comment: готово end = ''" можно задать любой разделитель. Или print(*b, sep = " ") более лаконично

Comment: опять же, мне надо чтобы это всё в итоге в какую то переменную например H впихнуть

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: Добавил в переменную `с`